# Photo App with Slicer

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to create my first App for iOS. I would like to create an App which can load a Photo from Library or create a new one with the camera. Then after when I created a photo or load a picture from my library, i would like that it will go to a filter, for example sepia (like it is used in every tutorial) and that I can change the value right now with a slicer on the screen. I will put my source code here, because I dont know if I am doing it right. This is everything from my ViewController.m file
What should I do now to get it working?

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
CIContext *context;
CIFilter *filter;
CIImage *beginImage;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"];
    NSURL *fileNamePath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
    CIImage *inputImage = [CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:fileNamePath];
    CIFilter *filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CISepia" keysAndValues:kCIInputImageKey, inputImage, @"inputIntensity", @0.8, nil];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];
   self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:outputImage];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)TakePhoto:(id)sender {

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)ChoosePhoto:(id)sender {

    picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    [picker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

}


-(void)imagePickerController:(nonnull UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(nonnull NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {

    image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    [self.ImageView setImage:image];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}

- (IBAction)amountSliderValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    float slideValue = _Slider.value;

    [filter setValue:@(slideValue)
              forKey:@"inputIntensity"];
    CIImage *outputImage = [filter outputImage];

    CGImageRef cgimg = [context createCGImage:outputImage
                                     fromRect:[outputImage extent]];

    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
    self.ImageView.image = newImage;

    CGImageRelease(cgimg);
}
```